# How can I make the score go up when a rectangle hits a moving image?

Tags: processing

I am making a game for my college project using Processing3. The game consists of a car which you control with your mouse that only moves on the x-axis. I have added in people and coins and they are also moving up and down on the x-axis. How can I make the score go up when a rectangle hits a moving image? I want the score to go up when the **rectangle** part of the car I created hits an **image** of a coin that is moving up and down on the road. I will appreciate as much help as possible as I honestly can't get my head around it. I have highlighted where I tried to fix my issue with the score. Here's my code:

```java
PImage sun,person1,person2,person3,person4,**coin**;
   int x,y;
   float ypos=0;
   float ypos2=4;
   **int coin_x,coin_y,coin_count;
   int score=0,lives=3;**

void setup()
   {
     size(1000,585);
     person1 = loadImage("person1.png");
     sun = loadImage("sun.png");
     **coin = loadImage("coin.png");**
     person2 = loadImage("person2.png");
     person3 = loadImage("person3.png");
     person4 = loadImage("person4.png");
     x=width/2;
     y=height/2;
   }
void draw()
{
  background(170,200,255);
  image(sun,720,-30,160,160);
  fill(255,240,50);
  ellipse(800,50,85,85);
  fill(200,255,150);
  rect(0,200,1000,400);
  fill(0,0,0);


  rect((-frameCount%200)*10+1000,130,90,70);
  rect((-frameCount%200)*10+1090,100,50,100);
  rect((-frameCount%200)*10+1500,130,90,70);
  rect((-frameCount%200)*10+1900,100,50,100);


  fill(200,200,200);
  rect(0,250,1000,90);
  fill(200,200,200);
  rect(0,350,1000,90);
  fill(200,200,200);
  rect(0,450,1000,90);
  fill(255,100,100);

  //vvvvvvvvv The car vvvvvvvvvvv
  **rect(0,mouseY+0,200,80);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(50,mouseY+60,60,60);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(150,mouseY+60,60,60);
  fill(100);
  ellipse(50,mouseY+60,40,40);
  fill(100);
  ellipse(150,mouseY+60,40,40);
  fill(255,100,100);
  arc(100,mouseY+0,160,150,PI,TWO_PI);
  fill(160,210,300);
  arc(100,mouseY+0,130,130,PI,TWO_PI);
  fill(255,100,100);
  rect(95,mouseY+0,10,-75);
  fill(0);
  rect(99,mouseY+0,2,80);**
  //^^^^^^^^^The car^^^^^^^^^


  image(person4,(-frameCount%300)*10+2500,250+sin(ypos)*100,120,120);
  ypos +=0.01;
  image(person3,(-frameCount%450)*5+2000,400+sin(ypos)*140,120,120);
  ypos +=0.01;
  image(person1,(-frameCount%300)*5+1000,300+sin(ypos)*50,120,120);
  ypos +=0.01;
  **image(coin,coin_x+(-frameCount%100)*20+1000,coin_y+300-sin(ypos2)*130,50,50);**
  ypos2 +=0.05;
  image(person2,(-frameCount%400)*5+1600,250-sin(ypos)*100,120,120);
  ypos +=0.08;
  **image(coin,coin_x+(-frameCount%300)*20+1900,coin_y+300+sin(ypos2)*130,50,50);
  ypos2 +=0.05;**


  **if((coin_x>10)&&(coin_x<10))
  {
    if(abs((coin_y+10)-(mouseY+0))<25)
    {
      coin_count++;
    }
  }**


  **textSize(30);
  fill(0);
  text("Score:"+coin_count,0,25);**


}
```

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question has also been posted here: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/25682/how-can-i-make-the-score-go-up-when-a-rectangle-hits-a-moving-image

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is the same as [the answer to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860782/873165). You need to perform rectangle-rectangle collision detection.

Google is still your friend here, but the basics look like this:

```
//evaluates to true if rectOne and rectTwo are colliding
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
```

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on collision detection in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

If you have no idea how to add this, then you need to start smaller. Try to create a program that shows two hard-coded rectangles that change color if they're colliding. Get that working perfectly before moving on to the next step.

If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post along with a more specific question. Note that this should not be your full project, but just a small example.